# How to add space between table cells `td`?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make modal window like window explorer when you see there is file column and Date with sort function, I got that working. I removed all borders from table, Now i want to add space between columns  `td` cell. how can I do that with CSS ?

main.css

```
table {
    border:none !important;
    border-spacing: 10px !important;
}
```

main.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>File</th>
        <th>
            <p ng-click="sortType = 'fileDate'; sortReverse = !sortReverse">
                Date
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'fileDate' && !sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
                <span ng-show="sortType == 'fileDate' && sortReverse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span>
            </p>
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="file in data | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse">
        <td ng-click="downloadServerFile(file.filename)" class="noBorder">{{file.filename}}
            <p class=" text-danger current-file-text" ng-if="file.mostRecent"><small>current file recording in progress</small><br></p>
        </td>
        <td class="noBorder">{{file.fileDate |date : 'medium'}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: i applied that but did not work

Comment: What do you mean add space? Like padding or a margin?

Comment: @MattCremeens it sounds like OP wants a big padding around their td elements so the contents simulates that each td never touches.

Comment: Thanks, @Martin. That's what I guessed, but just wasn't clear to me.

Comment: i just want space between columns that represent `td`

Comment: @hussain then Matts answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Unable to reproduce - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dpyOjz

Comment: Well, that will add space around `td` but i just want to add space between columns

Comment: edited my question

Comment: ...answer provided.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a situation where you just want padding between the columns and not on the top and bottom or each `td`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm thinking you want to add something like this

```
td {
    padding: 50px;
}
```

or just use `padding-right` if you don't need padding on the top and bottom.

```
td {
    padding-right: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

> i just want to add space between columns

`border-spacing` takes two values, horizontal & vertical.

E.g.

```
/* border-spacing: horizontal vertical */
border-spacing: 1% 2em;
```

[**MDN Reference**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

```css
table {
    border:none !important;
    border-spacing: 10px 0 !important;
    /* override bootstrap default */
    border-collapse:separate !important;
}
  
  td {
  background: pink;
  padding: 1em;
  /* for demo only - not a border */
  outline:1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: see again padding on td will add space around the cells , i dont want to do that i just want space between two `td` e.g above i have two cells in a row i need a space between columns not around cell itself. I hope i explained better.

Comment: No...padding is **inside** the cells not outside.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table>
    <tr> 
        <td>One</td> 
        <td>Two</td> 
        <td>Three</td> 
        <td>Four</td> 
    </tr>
</table>

td:nth-of-type(2) {
padding-right: 20px;
}
```